# Objective C: App freezes when using a timer

Tags: objective-c, timer, freeze

It took me hours to figure out how to implement a timer into my program, but when it runs, the app doesn't load completely as it did before the timer.

In my main.m:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {  
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 OutLauncher *theLauncher = [[OutLauncher alloc] init];
NSTimer *theTimer = [theLauncher getTimer];
[theTimer retain];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: theTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

 [pool release];
 return 0;  
 }
```

The file OutLauncher is being imported into that, which looks like this:

```
- (void)doStuff {  
NSLog( @"Doing Stuff");  

}

 - (NSTimer *)getTimer{  
 NSTimer *theTimer;

 theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector: @selector(doStuff) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 return [theTimer autorelease];
}
```

The timer works, the console updates every second with the phrase "doing stuff" but the rest of the program just won't load. It will if I comment out the code I added to int main though

Comment: Is this a Mac or iOS app? What is OutLauncher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

You don't need to autorelease the timer you return after setting one up with [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:]  It is already autoreleased.

The timer created via scheduledTimerWithInterval is already added to the default run loop.  So you don't need to use the following:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: theTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

In fact, you don't even need to keep a reference to the timer unless you need to cancel it yourself.

Comment: I got rid of those and it loads up, but of course a new problem arises. In my:   - (void)doStuff {
 test.text = @"test";
 
 NSLog(@"go");
  
}   it won't run anything other than nslog

Answer (score 0):

Here is what apple has to say about what you are doing [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **run**
>
> Puts the receiver into a permanent
>   loop, during which time it processes
>   data from all attached input sources.
>
> - (void)run Discussion If no input sources or timers are attached to the
>     run loop, this method exits
>     immediately; otherwise, it runs the
>     receiver in the NSDefaultRunLoopMode
>     by repeatedly invoking
>     runMode:beforeDate:. In other words,
>     this method effectively begins an
>     infinite loop that processes data from
>     the run loop’s input sources and
>     timers.
>
> Manually removing all known input
>   sources and timers from the run loop
>   is not a guarantee that the run loop
>   will exit. Mac OS X can install and
>   remove additional input sources as
>   needed to process requests targeted at
>   the receiver’s thread. Those sources
>   could therefore prevent the run loop
>   from exiting.
>
> If you want the run loop to terminate,
>   you shouldn't use this method.
>   Instead, use one of the other run
>   methods and also check other arbitrary
>   conditions of your own, in a loop. A
>   simple example would be:
>
> BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;
>   // global NSRunLoop *theRL =
>   [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; while
>   (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL
>   runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
>   beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
>   where shouldKeepRunning is set to NO
>   somewhere else in the program.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later.

So it looks like your code is doing what it is supposed to do. It is Logging all the timer events and waiting indefinitely for the run loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making it a lot more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to put any code in your main.m file. If you want to fire the `doStuff` method every second, this is all the code you need:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector: @selector(doStuff) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You don't need to (auto)release it yourself. `timer` is already autoreleased. If you want to be able to cancel the timer, you will need to keep a reference of it. Then when you want to cancel, you just call `invalidate` and set the reference to `nil`.